# Building a Linked-List with another Struct - Append Function runtime error

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

First whack at learning pointers, I'm trying to follow all of this and I thought I had it right but alas I am getting a runtime error when calling the append function. The CSV function appears to be working. I'm guessing I've messed up the Append flow. Any tips or advise is warmly welcomed.

```
struct Car {
    string carId; // unique identifier
    string title;
   
};


class LinkedList {

private:

    struct node {
        Car cars;
        node *next; //is this storing the memory address of the struct? 
    };

    // alias for node pointer (memory address of node)
    typedef struct node* nodePtr;

    // defining pointer variables for memory positions in the List
    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
    nodePtr tail; //is this needed


public:
    LinkedList();
    void Append(Car car);
};

//Default constructor

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

}

void LinkedList::Append(Car car) {
    
    nodePtr n = new node;
        n->cars = car;
        n->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL){
        head = n;
        tail =n;

    }
    else {
        tail->next = n;
        tail=n;
    }
}
```

---

```
void loadCars(string csvPath, LinkedList *list) {
      
    csv::Parser file = csv::Parser(csvPath);

    try {
        // loop to read rows of a CSV file
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < file.rowCount(); i++) {

            // initialize a bid using data from current row (i)
            Car car ;
            car.carId = file[i][1];
            car.title = file[i][0];
                    
            // add this bid to the end
            list->Append(car);
        }
    } 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

LinkedList carlist
csvPath = xyz; 

loadCars(csvPath, &carlist);

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to any error: `nodePtr curr;` and `nodePtr temp;` should not be class members. Instead they should be local variables in whatever function that needs them.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including actual caller code, not psuedocodes.

Comment: I don't believe the bug is in the code that is presented in the question.

Comment: You will probably have to spend some time with a debugger stepping through your algorithm 1 line at a time and looking at the variables at each step. Don't just run your program in the debugger actively use it to investigate  what is happening at each line of your code.

Comment: Please post a [mre], something that can be copied and compiled to reproduce the error (while still not containing more code than needed to reproduce the error). The current code relies on an undefined `csv` namespace, which makes it incomplete. At the same time, if the error is in the append flow, you should not need a `csv::Parser` -- hardcode values to append to your list instead.

Comment: What is the exact error, what is in the call stack?